# How to handle a cookie banner

Tags: reactjs, google-tag-manager

I have a project in ReactJS.
I have a cookie banner:

```
const [consent, setConsent] = useState({
    essential: true,
    analytics: false,
    marketing: false,
  });

  const [displayBanner, setDisplayBanner] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const hasConsent = localStorage.getItem("cookieConsent");
    if (!hasConsent) {
      setDisplayBanner(true);
    }
  }, []);

  const handleConsentChange = (event) => {
    const { name, checked } = event.target;
    setConsent((prevConsent) => ({
      ...prevConsent,
      [name]: checked,
    }));
  };

  const handleAcceptAll = () => {
    setConsent({
      essential: true,
      analytics: true,
      marketing: true,
    });

    localStorage.setItem("cookieConsent", "true");
    setDisplayBanner(false);
  };

  const handleAcceptSelected = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("cookieConsent", "true");
    setDisplayBanner(false);
  };

  const handleReject = () => {
    setDisplayBanner(false);
  };
```

I have a Google Tag Manager code (GTM-XXXXXXX).

How to handle GTM in React?

What if the user does not consent to marketing but consents to the rest? How to handle this?

I would like to handle GTM correctly.
What if only some of the consents are accepted? How to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

In short: in React, you only load the banner and GTM. The actual blocking has to be done within GTM. There's an option to block the whole TMS (tag management system) altogether, but it's a crude solution and not the best practice.

You must have access to current consent from the global scope. Usually cookies suffice.

The theory is simple: in GTM, you add a proper blocking trigger to every tag that needs blocking depending on the consent given.

After the banner is loaded and before the consent is given, the banner vendor (or your own logic) should set up default consent as the law demands. Some jurisdictions allow tracking by default; others don't.